# Combinatorics in SQL: "Choose" Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Using PLSQL Developer and looking for a simple function for `n choose k`.  I just can't find it via Google, since I keep getting information about `CASE` when I search "Choose".  Thanks!

Comment: ...or do I have to create my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [knowledge found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination):

```
function combination(n in integer, k in integer)
    return integer
is
    l_result integer;
begin
    for i in 1..k loop
        l_result := l_result * (n-i+1) / k;
    end loop;
    return l_result;
end;
/
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Yes, I see I have go the self-defined function route.  Thanks.